# communication between android and two php web servers

Tags: php

I have **two php web server** ,one of them communicate with a client (android) ,I want to know how can i easily make communication between the two servers,**it means how can i redirecting data, which have transfered from android**, (on a web service) to the first web server,**to the other web server**

Just i want to mentioned that i succeed in sending data from android to the first web server so to be clear my problem is transferring ***automatically without human intervention*** data from the first web server to the second once the first web server received the data from android.
hope you'll help me with your ideas and I'm sorry for my English.
Thanks a lot

Comment: This is too broad without some more detailed information. What kind of data is it, what platform do the two servers run, etc.

Comment: What kind of data are you talking about ? are you not using a Database ?

Comment: why do you need to move the data? how does the data need to be transfered? why can't you use a central database? [what have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com)?

Comment: yes i have a database in every server 
the first server is a merchant server and the second is for a gateway payment. so i searching here how the gateway payment and the merchant server could communicate ????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the cURL library in PHP on the first (proxy) to make a request to the second server.

Check out [PHP cURL manual](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php). Also see the example below. In this example I send a `JSON` request to a server for authentication. You can easily adapt it to send a `POST` request or whatever else you need:

```
<?php

$fld = array(
    'registration_ids' => array('1234'),
    'data' => array('header' => 'abc', 'message' => 'def'));
$hdr = array(
    'Content-Type: application/json',
    'Authorization: key=ghi');

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://example.com:9777');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PORT, 9777);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $hdr);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fld));

$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: ok i have to be more clear, 
the first server present a place for shopping so the client connect on android and pick all the products that he go to buy it so the first server present a  **merchant server** and the second server is for verify the credential (confidential code client ) for accepting take money from the client account,it's a Payment Gateway.

the two server are in php, hope you help me

Comment: I'm so confused 
how can i make that echo back please

Comment: @menzous -- The answer I provided is correct for your question in the fact that you should use cURL to make an http request from the **merchant server** to the second server. Please see the manual as per the attached link.

Comment: I have edited my answer appropriately.

Comment: thanks a lot @neelsg 
I see it and i start now to learning it but please have you some tutorials about that.also is there any thing that i have to install  in my two server to start work with this curl function ?????

Comment: I added an example in my answer. cURL should be a standard library included with you PHP installation on the servers, so you shouldn't need to install anything extra.

Comment: really you save my life :) :)
thanks a lot